# App screen with map and info panel should hide and show panel on button click or down sliding

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a new Flutter project that should show a Google Map on the upper screen half and a panel with information and actions on the lower screen half, like you may see on the screenshot:

[image]

I want to create a way to hide the panel and show the map on full screen when the user taps on the close button or when the user slides down the panel and the other way also, the user should be able to click on a button to get the initial view.
Here you have the body of the class:

```
body: Stack(
          children: [
            GoogleMap(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottomPaddingOfMap),
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              compassEnabled:true,
                myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                myLocationEnabled: true,
                zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                zoomControlsEnabled: true,
                initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
                _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
                newGoogleMapController = controller;

                setState(() {
                  bottomPaddingOfMap = 300.0;
                });

                locatePosition();

                },
            ),
            //extra hamburger Drawer
            Positioned(
              top: 45.0,
              left: 22.0,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();

                },

                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        blurRadius: 6.0,
                        spreadRadius: 0.5,
                        offset: Offset(
                        0.7,
                        0.7,
                      ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.black,),
                    ),
                  ),
              ),
              ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
                bottom: 0.0,
              child: Container(
                height: 350.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(18.0), topRight: Radius.circular(18.0)),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      blurRadius: 16.0,
                      spreadRadius: 0.5,
                      offset: Offset(0.7, 0.7),
                    )
                  ]
                ),

                child:

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 18.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Center(
                        child: SizedBox(
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              RaisedButton.icon(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.cake),
                                label: Text("Close"),

                                onPressed: (){
                                  print("pulsaado");
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 6.0,),
                      Text("Hi there!", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),

                      Text("Where do you want to create an alert?", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontFamily: "Brand-Bold"),),
                      SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                      Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              blurRadius: 6.0,
                              spreadRadius: 0.5,
                              offset: Offset(0.7, 0.7),
                            ),
                          ],
                      ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.blueAccent ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                              Text("Search Drop Off"),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 24.0,),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.grey,),
                          SizedBox(width: 12.0,),
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text("Add Home"),
                                SizedBox(height: 4.0,),
                                Text("Your living home address", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 12.0),),

                              ],

                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                      DividerWidget(),
                      SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.grey,),
                          SizedBox(width: 12.0,),
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text("Add Work"),
                              SizedBox(height: 4.0,),
                              Text("Your office address", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 12.0),),

                            ],

                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I would appreciate your proposals to achieve the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you have to change three things:
First, transform from StatelessWidget to StatefulWidget;
Second, create a variable for the height of the container and initialized whit the initial height;
Thread, you have to change the container with an AnimatedContaire ad crate a function onPressd Like this:

```
AnimatedContainer(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black,
          blurRadius: 6.0,
          spreadRadius: 0.5,
          offset: Offset(0.7, 0.7),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1),
    height: heigntValue,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (heigntValue == 350) {
                      heigntValue -= 300;
                    } else {
                      heigntValue += 300;
                    }
                    print(heigntValue);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Close I did show something that would indicate slide down

```
▼ ==== ▼
```

and

```
▲ ==== ▲
```

to slide up